# Stroing a list in redis-py

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

I'm trying to store a list generated from a dict in my redis db, using the following commands:

```
x = {'TLV-IST#2022-12-27~2023-01-04': '252', 'TLV-IST#2022-12-27~2023-01-17': '300'}

for key, value in x.items():
    client.lpush(key[:7], key[8:] + '#' + value)
```

but I'm getting this error:
"WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value"

Although when I'm using a 'regular' string (such as: client.lpush('key', 'value')) it works,
what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine on my machine. You may have some typo error in your real source code?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dictionary have you thought about using (redis-stack)[https://hub.docker.com/r/redis/redis-stack] docker? That allows you to store your native dict using json.set().

Here are some further examples on usage: https://redis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/search_json_examples.html#Adding-a-JSON-document-to-an-index

Comment: I'm not interested in a JSON format, only a simple list.